# How to validate form before submitting using formsy-react-components?

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs, validation, react-native

I'm using formsy-react-components to make a form and I want to validate its input fields before submitting the form.
Is there any way to do that using formsy-react-components?

```html
<form onChange={this.validateForm} onValidSubmit={this.handleSubmit} ref='form'>
  <Input type='text' value={this.state.id} className='form-   control' validations="isNumeric"></Input>
  <Input type='text' value={this.state.name}  className='form-control' validations="isAlpha"></Input>
</form>
```

The inputs with errors have the css class `has-error` which I then style according to my needs.
Now I want to validate form before changing anything in the input fields or submitting the form. Is there any way to do that?
I've tried looking here: https://github.com/christianalfoni/formsy-react/blob/master/examples/custom-validation/app.js.
But I wasn't able to find what I need.
Maybe someone who has already used this library can guide me how to go about this, or how to validate form when mounting the component.

Comment: Perhaps by invoking this method on the element https://github.com/christianalfoni/formsy-react/blob/master/API.md#isvalidvalue ?

Comment: i think by default formsy-react will validate on component mount if the fields have value. And the validations happens only if you have specified `required` and `validations` on the field inputs.

Comment: I think the question is really, given that formsy can validate on attempting to submit, how in React do you determine whether formsy considers the form fills validated or not, so you can act accordingly?